# How to poll in AWS SDK Java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS sdk java. I am trying to write a code through which I want to control the instance and to get all AWS EC2 information. 
I am able to start an instance and also stop it. But as you all must be aware that it takes some time to start an instance, so I want to wait there (don't want to use Thread.sleep) till it's up or when I'm stopping an instance it should wait there till I proceed to the next step.
Here's the code:

```
   AmazonEC2 ec2 = = new AmazonEC2Client(credentialsProvider);

   DescribeInstancesResult describeInstancesRequest = ec2.describeInstances();
   List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();
   Set<Instance> instances = new HashSet<Instance>();

   for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
     instances.addAll(reservation.getInstances());
   }

   for (Instance instance : instances) {
   if ((instance.getInstanceId().equals("myimage"))) {
         List<String> instancesToStart = new ArrayList<String>();
         instancesToStart.add(instance.getInstanceId());
         StartInstancesRequest startr = new StartInstancesRequest();
         startr.setInstanceIds(instancesToStart);
         ec2.startInstances(startr);
         Thread.currentThread().sleep(60*1000);
 }

  if ((instat.getName()).equals("running")) {
         List<String> instancesToStop = new ArrayList<String>();

         instancesToStop.add(instance.getInstanceId());
         StopInstancesRequest stoptr = new StopInstancesRequest();
         stoptr.setInstanceIds(instancesToStop);
         ec2.stopInstances(stoptr);
  }
```

Also, I'd like to say that whenever I try to get the list of images it hangs in the below code.

```
   DescribeImagesResult describeImagesResult = ec2.describeImages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an instance of the class "Instance" every time you want to see the updated status with the same "instance Id".

```
Instance instance = new Instance(<your instance id that you got previously from describe instances>);
```

To get the updated status with something like this:

```
InstanceStatus instat = instance.getStatus();
```

I think the key here is saving the "instance id" of the instance that you care about.

boto in Python has an nice method `instance.update()` that can be called on an instance and you can see its status but I can't find it in Java.

Hope this helps.